# Ubuntu folder permission

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I ran this code

```
sudo chown -R mtlive /var/www/html/
```

And

```
sudo chown -R mtlive:nogroup /var/www/html/
```

this is my Vsftpd folder. But i cant upload file from my client to server . Why The permission seem

```
dr-xr-xr-x 2 mtlive nogroup 4096 Sep 16 16:26 . 
drwxr-xr-x 4 mtlive nogroup 4096 Sep 16 16:35 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 mtlive nogroup 11321 Sep 16 16:18 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 mtlive nogroup 24 Sep 16 16:26 info.php
```

I want to give all permissions to mtlive for using the html folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include yourself into the `www-data` group. ([AddUsersHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddUsersHowto))
Use:

```
sudo adduser mtlive www-data
```

That way you can add things to directories where `www-data` owns the group.
Now you need 755 permissions:

```
sudo chmod 755 -R /var/www
```

Without changing permission, it can't be accessed.

Comment: I get this error ..
331 Please specify the password.
Komut: PASS ******
Yanıt: 500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()

Comment: Tty to set inside /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf allow_writable_root=YES

Comment: ECONNREFUSED  I get this error now :/ I am used this way for upload vsftpd https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-16-04